# If is custom post type archive page

Tags: custom-post-types

If I need to check custom post post type is movie, I can use following code.

```
if ( 'movie' == get_post_type() )
```

I need to check, if it is **custom post post type Archives Page**? ( www.domain.com/movie)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out is_post_type_archive() in [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

```
if( is_post_type_archive('movie') )
{
    //do my thing
}
```

Comment: Beware, this affects admin edit page (/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=movie&all_posts=1) too! E.g. if you set `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );` you will see only three movies in admin. It's not too clear from the codex if checking that we are on the archive frontend is what the function should do, but if yes, it doesn't work good.

Comment: At least that's what I got with hooking into `pre_get_posts` and changing query on `if( is_post_type_archive('movie')` condition